# How to capture react events during a refresh update due to a focus onBlur change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-table

Code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-table-editable-content-ggvcy

When I update the text in my table and I have an `onBlur` event to persist that data change to state I want my user to click a save button the save button click is missed.

I believe it is missed because the table is refreshing due to the state change of `data`.

Can anybody help me understand ways to capture the onClick event when it triggers the `onBlur` rerender?

Comment: I think that it might be the same issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57419587/3877913 what happens when instead of using the component ReactTable you try using the hook useTable. You can take another look at the hook example here https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/5145a632c944d135863d8a2f14a160a2f9395f61/examples/editable-data/src/App.js#L90

Comment: Also note that you might need to use react-table v7 which is still in alpha if you want to use hooks. v6 don’t play well with hooks https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table/v/7.0.0-alpha.21

Answer (score 0):

```
const updateCellData = (idx, id, value) => {
    console.log(`idx: ${idx}, id: ${id}`);
    const newData = [...data];
    newData[idx][id] = value;
    console.log(`prev: ${data[idx][id]}, new: ${newData[idx][id]}`);
    // setData(newData);
};
```

I realized that i am mutating the state because i am not deep copying the object. Strangely this works for my use case since my data is server side and it updates as needed but I would never recommend directly mutating the state.